# Silverlight URI loading Image

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, uri

I am trying to load an Image in Silverlight, but i keep getting a null pointer exception when i assign it to this.Image1.Source. I've looked over similiar stack questions, but none of them solve the problem. My image file is in a folder right next to the xap file.

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri("Content/button.png", UriKind.Relative);
        var image = new BitmapImage { UriSource = new Uri("Content/button.png", UriKind.Relative) };
        try
        {
            BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage(uri);
            this.image1.Source = image;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            string problem = e.Message;
        }

        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i've found the problem, i was trying to assign image to image1.Source, but image1 was not yet created - it is created in the InitilizeComponent() function.